# how to put text on floating action bar (fab) in android, let the action bar be cart and text be number of items

Tags: android, text, floating-action-button

[Screenshot from Bigbasket App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ISHc.png)

I have achieved same thing by custom layout. But is there way we can put text above fab provided by android.

Answer (score 3):

The [FloatingActionButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html) extends ImageButton, which does not support text.

If you want to achieve the effect in your link using the native FloatingActionButton, you'll need to create a different icon for each digit you want to represent.

Answer (score 0):

Add a textview and make it above the floating action button at centre using relative layout params and elevation attribute. You need to check for click of both I guess.
You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33953223/how-to-add-a-textview-above-a-floatingactionbutton-in-android) for elevation attribute.