# How to add a TextView above a FloatingActionButton in Android

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I want to add a TextView above a FloatingActionButton, I use the FrameLayout as the parent layout of the TextView and FloatingActionButton, here is my sample code:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:backgroundTint="#00fff0"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        app:fabSize="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="above"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

but it's useless, the TextView is below the FloatingActionButton, like this
[image]

and I want it show like this:
[image]

I am poor for this, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You just need to add an elevation attribute to the textview

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:backgroundTint="#00fff0"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        app:fabSize="normal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="above"
        android:elevation="7dp"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Welcome.. happy coding :)

Comment: use `app:elevation` to support version lower than API 21.

Comment: You set the FAB elevation to zero, doesn't that defeat the purpose of having a FAB if it doesn't have elevation.  My point is that this doesn't work if you don't set app:elevation of the FAB to zero.  Try setting FAB to elevation 7 and textview to 8, textview still will not appear on top.

Answer (score 7):

it a z-order problem. In your FrameLayout move the `<TextView` above the `<FloatingActionButton`

```
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="above"/>

  <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:backgroundTint="#00fff0"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    app:fabSize="normal" />
</FrameLayout>
```

should do it

Comment: I have try it, and it's useless

Comment: Beautiful! Worked like a charm for API>21. Had to give elevation to TV instead. You can do either of the thing. **give elevation to TextView or remove elevation from FAB**

Answer (score 4):

To support low end device use both `android:elevation`  and `app:elevation`

set both values to 0 for Fab

```
 <FrameLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:backgroundTint="#00fff0"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    app:fabSize="normal" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="above"/>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution :

```
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:backgroundTint="#00fff0"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    app:fabSize="normal" />

<TextView
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:text="above"/>
</RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set elevations for both views accordingly.  Also, it makes more sense for you to move your TextView XML code above your FAB XML code.